# Weird error: use of \rotatebox command causes boldface text to become persistent in xetex

Tags: xetex

Please see this MWE given below (excerpted from a much larger
document) where we are using two languages. English is the main
language, and [Bengali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengali_language) is the second language.

```
\documentclass{article}

% For bilingual document
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

% Times New Roman used
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

% Bangla
\setotherlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontbf[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifonttt[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontsf[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{SolaimanLipi}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{bengali}

  \textbf{Text One}

  \textbf{টেক্সস্ট এক}

  % If the following line is commented out, the problem will disappear
  \rotatebox{90}{rotated text}

  Text Two

  টেক্সস্ট দুই

\end{bengali}

Text Three

\end{document}
```

The problem is, the line containing the command,
`\rotatebox{90}{rotated text}` is causing the `\textbf` to become
persistent. After long agonizing hours, it has been detected that
if the said line is commented out, the problem disappears.

[image]

As you can see from the above output, the "Text Two" and
subsequent lines are in boldface. But they are not supposed to be
like this.

The problem is not remedied even when the 
`\rotatebox` line is put between curly braces.

The problem will not happen in a monolingual English document.

How do we tackle this problem?

*(The Bengali font used can be found [here](https://www.omicronlab.com/download/fonts/SolaimanLipi_20-04-07.ttf).)*

Comment: The problem is with `AutoFakeBold` for the main font. If you use a font that has a real bold, e.g. Bangla MN the problem disappears.